# spring log service and transactions

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

in my app which is based on struts2, spring IoC and Transasctions, jpa, Hibernate i want to introduce an "audit log function" which will log all the important events, such as : a user has been created/updated, or a ticket was opened by somebody...
I want to keep this log in the database so for this i will have a DAO. I created also a service class for this purpose 'AuditLogService' which will have transactional behavior " propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" due to the fact that i want to log the event no matter if the logged event was successful or not.
The problem is that if i have something like this in my user service :

```
@Override
public boolean saveUser(UserDto userDto) {

    User u = new User();        
    u.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
    u.setLastName(userDto.getLastName());
    u.setUserName(userDto.getUserName());       
    u.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());
    u.setIsLdapUser(userDto.getIsLdapUser());
    u.setId(userDto.getId());
    u.setAgentId(userDto.getAgentId());

    Boolean eventStatus = true;
        String event="";
    try{        
        if (u.getId()!=null){           
            dao.update(u);
            event = "UPDATE_USER";
        }else{
            dao.create(u);
            event = "CREATE_USER";          
        }           
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        eventStatus = false;
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        AuditLogEvent ale = auditLogEventDao.getAuditLogEvent(event);
        auditLogService.addAuditLogEvent(ale, eventStatus,u.toString());
    }

    return false;
}
```

the audit log method is executed before committing the save user method and reports that the event was true, but in fact the event was false.
Any idea how can i solve this ? or maybe this approach is not the best... ?

- updates !
  After Michael`s advices i have transformed my Service also into an Aspect

  ```
  @Aspect  
  @Service
  class AuditLogAspectImpl implements AuditLogAspect {
      @Autowired
      private AuditLogDao dao;

  @Autowired
  private UserDao userDao;

  @Override
  @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* xxx.yy.services..*.save*(..))", returning = "retVal")   
  public boolean afterLogEvent(JoinPoint joinPoint,Object retVal){
  }
  ```

  }

and now i have my method signature like here. everything works ok, i can detect if a operation failed or was successful and i can log this into a log file, but if i want to log this into a table from database via a dao class, when the operations fail and the transaction is rolled back my audit entry is not inserted.
First i thought that this is happening because the both operations, the actual method that need to be audited and the audit event are running in the same transactional context, and if one of them is rolled back the entire transaction is, and i have created a new transaction for the aspect logging part. But this seems not to work.

Any ideea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is not correct, because the declarative transaction are implemented through an around advice (AOP) so the whole method executes, including your finally block with the audit, then returns and the transaction is committed.

I'd recommend to write your own auditing Aspect as something like auditing or logging is a prime example for cross cutting concerns.

Have a look at [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

I'd go with the [After (finally) advice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-after-finally) so you can audit failed and successful stuff.

It's actually not that complicated… You won't need AspectJ, Spring Aspects will be enough for the given purpose.

Comment: Spring AOP is per default interface proxy based. That means, that a call from the outside uses the proxy, which is fine. The transaction introduces a proxy as well as AOP. No problem here. But the AOP proxy calls the original service addAuditLogEvent and the transaction is probably not applied. You need both: Your auditing aspect and a separate service. Autowire the service into the aspect.

Comment: Great, after i followed you advice and create a new service, which is executed with REQUIRED_NEW transaction everything is working as expected

Comment: @VideanuAdrian Hi I am having the same problem. Can you elaborate in deails about how you fixed this? What did you mean by `create a new service` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quincy, I have created a new service class (AuditLogServiceImpl implements AuditLogService) and this was injected into AuditLogAspectImpl with @Inject. The the addAuditLogEvent(AuditLogEvent ale) from AuditLogServiceImpl has the REQURES_NEW transactional setting. In my case this was accomplished by AOP like this :  <tx:method name="addAuditLogEvent" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" read-only="false"/>

Comment: @VideanuAdrian I got it now. The `@Aspect` class and the actual `@Transaction` class have to be split into different classes. This kind of programming pattern is quite a stopper for spring newbies like me...Thanks!